# Sum duration when metric was above/below threshold in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Consider a counter `my_counter` with a label `success`. I created a success rate metric with this query: `rate(my_counter[10m]{success="true"})/rate(my_counter[10m])`.

Now I want to know how much time the rate was below a certain threshold. I have a Grafana dashboard with Prometheus as its data source. With Grafana I can easily pick a time range, but I still need a way to sum the time where my condition applies.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

There are four parts to your question:

1. have an indicator that takes value 1 when a condition is met - this is done by using the `BOOL` operator of [comparison operators](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#comparison-binary-operators).

   rate(something[5m]) > BOOL 0.99
2. compute the number of time the condition is met - this is done by using the [avg_over_time](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time) function:

   avg_over_time(condition[1d])
3. get everything in a single query - you need to use recoding rules or have a prometheus version that support [subqueries](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/examples/#subquery)
4. and the last is to use grafana to fill in the time frame to get either the ratio or the duration the condition was met.

   avg_over_time( condition[$__range] )

   avg_over_time( condition[$__range] ) * $__range_s

Putting it all together is a hard-to-read expression. You may do better using the `-- Grafana Dashboard --` source available in recent versions:

```
avg_over_time( (rate(something[5m]) > BOOL 0.99)[$__range:] )
```